# Replace tokens in yaml file python

Tags: python, yaml

I have the following yaml file config.yml:

```
PATH1: /this/is/the/first/path
PATH2: $PATH1/plus/second/path
```

I read it in python in this way:

```
import yaml

with open("../etc/test.yml", "r") as f:
    config = yaml.safe_load(f)
print(config)
```

and this is obviously what I get when I print config dictionary:

```
{'PATH2': '$PATH1/plus/second/path', 'PATH1': '/this/is/the/first/path'}
```

What I would have instead is:

```
{'PATH2': '/this/is/the/first/path/plus/second/path', 'PATH1': '/this/is/the/first/path'}
```

Is there any built-in way to achieve this goal?
Or I have to create something to replace them on my own?

Answer (score 1):

PY-yaml library doesn't resolve environment variables by default. You need to define an implicit resolver that will find the regex that defines an environment variable and execute a function to resolve it.

this is a link that can help you do it
https://newbedev.com/how-to-replace-environment-variable-value-in-yaml-file-to-be-parsed-using-python-script